# Cannot access tab DOM using React + Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to create a firefox extension using React.
The purpose of the extension is to click on some button in the popup window of the extension and for it to get data from the tab (from specific elements).
While using the document variable it returns me the HTML of the extension itself (which makes sense) but how can I get the tab information (The HTML elements) and extract data from them?
I also tried using `content.document.getElementsByTagName('*')` to get the content of the tab but it content does not exist.

Thanks,